# Sort array of strings using another array of strings in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I want to sort array1 using array2.

```
var array1 = ["cat","dog","mouse","elephant","ant","cow","goat","hen"];
var array2 = ["mouse","cow","goat"];

The result should look like
var another_array = ["mouse","cow","goat", "bird"--- then rest of the values in array1]
```

Comment: This is not a challenge site.  We answer questions.  You have to try.  Please show us what you have done and why it is not working.

Comment: I don't think this is sorting. This is concentration of two arrays. You can use `var another_array  = [...array2, ...array1]`

Comment: @MaheerAli That will include all duplicates which is not the requested behavior

Comment: where is `'bird'` coming from?

Comment: And when the item is not in the array what happens? You say it is at the end, is there no sorting? What happens really changes the answer

Comment: @NinaScholz mistakenly added "bird" .

Comment: @Maheer If i concat arrays the result will not what i need.I want to have array2 values in array1 at first place.Then other values which is not in array2.

Comment: @Hogan I was working on a project and found a problem something like that I just simplify the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for concatenation and filtering:

```
>>> array2.concat(array1.filter(i => !array2.includes(i)))
    ["mouse", "cow", "goat", "cat", "dog", "elephant", "ant", "hen"]
```

Comment: Failing an edge case not specified in the question doesn't make it wrong or downvote-worthy, but that would be a good improvement for this answer.

Comment: What if array two included "bird"?  then you would add it to the result.

Comment: Nowhere was it specified the input sort array could contain values not in the base array... I always find it silly when answers are made to be fully foolproof when it's just as easy to simply use the helper as it was intended :) if array two included bird, maybe it would fit the sample output better then!

Answer (score 2):

Just taken from object with the order the value or `Infinity` for the delta.

```js
var array1 = ["cat", "dog", "mouse", "elephant", "ant", "cow", "goat", "hen"],
    array2 = ["mouse", "cow", "goat"],
    order = array2.reduce((r, k, i) => (r[k] = i + 1, r), {});

array1.sort((a, b) => (order[a] || Infinity) - (order[b] || Infinity));

console.log(array1);
```

Comment: What if the 2nd list has items not in the first list?

Comment: then you the the original sorting (if the user agent has a stable sorting).

Comment: what if array2 had another element "bird"

Comment: @Hogan That won't affect the result in any way.

Comment: nothing happens, because `array1` gets the order, even if the delta is greater.

Comment: That seems overkill

Comment: @mplungjan, right, this item looks like a placeholder for inbetween or is just debris.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this - concatenation and a filter

```js
const array1 = ["cat","dog","mouse","elephant","ant","cow","goat","hen"];
const array2 = ["mouse","cow","goat"];
const anotherArray = [...array2,
                         "bird",
                      ...array1.filter(item => !array2.includes(item))]
console.log(anotherArray)
```

Comment: hey, no `'bird'`... ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Use **concat** function

```js
var hege = ["Cecilie", "Lone"];
var stale = ["Emil", "Tobias", "Linus"];
var children = hege.concat(stale); 
console.log(children)
```

Comment: This includes duplicates

Comment: What if array two included "bird"?  then you would add it to the result.  Also you will have dups